# how to implement mock server

Tags: mocking, postman, wiremock, mockserver

I need to deploy and configure server that will response that I need.
for example if I send:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="" targetNamespace="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="PayDoc">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="absAcceptDate" minOccurs="0" type="xs:dateTime">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Время принятия электронного документа в АБС банка</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="acceptIndividual" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
....
```

server must response another xml schema with request values

Answer (score 0):

steps to create mock server in postman:

1. create a collection and request
2. add an example

in example just paste the response as you want

[image]
3. click the collection and click create mock server

[image]

Thats it https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/setting-up-mock/